# pygame - get current color of text (pygame.Surface type)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I want to randomize colors and change color for text every few seconds, so I want to make sure that I dont use the same color. How can I know the current color of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) of the colors and use the difference of the set and the current color to get a set which only contains different colors. Then convert it into a list and use `random.choice` to pick a new color.

```
import random

RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
# Define a set of the colors.
COLORS = {RED, GREEN, BLUE}
color = RED  # Current color.

for _ in range(50):
    # The difference of `COLORS` and the set `{color}` is
    # a set that doesn't contain `color`.
    difference = COLORS - {color}
    # Then you need to convert this set into a list in order
    # to use `random.choice`.
    color = random.choice(list(difference))
    print(color)
```

Comment: So there is no way to know the current color, am I right?

Comment: If you store it in a variable, you know the current color. There's also the [`pygame.Surface.get_at`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at) method which allows you to see which color a specific pixel of the text surface has, but you don't know if it's a pixel of the actual text or the transparent background of the surface, so you'd have to call `get_at` multiple times with a `for` or `while` loop until you get a non-transparent pixel. And because of the antialiasing there will be different shades of the color.